# Reactadmin - edit user roles

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have two different components User and Role. There is a many-to-many relationship between User and Role.

Is there any solution how should I get all User roles in a edit window?

The exact field like I have in my `UserCreate` action:

```
<ReferenceArrayInput 
    source="UserRoles" 
    reference="Role"
    sort={{ field: 'Name', order: 'ASC' }}
  >
    <SelectArrayInput optionText="Name"/>
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

Image how it should look like [link](https://prnt.sc/n0wmu8)

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have already tried to combine ReferenceArrayInput and ReferenceManyField to achieve a goal to have all current user roles and should be able to edit them.

But it is not good solution, I was just my idea. I don't have any other ideas how should i solve this. Should i call API call for data and use them somehow with ReferenceArrayInput, or how this can be done?

Comment: Could you add a code snippet to the question? That way people could recommend you more things

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @StefanBecker I edited the question, I would like to know how this should be done, not the full code